# How to set a workbook to a variable name?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

How do I set a workbook to a variable name to be used later on in the sub?

I'm trying to open a workbook (PriceFile) and set values in this workbook to values in the original workbook (TestFile). I can open PriceFile but can't name the workbook.

```
Public Sub Get_Sum_Assured()
    Dim TestFile As Workbook
    Dim PriceFile As Workbook
    Dim PriceFileName As String
    Dim Test_Cases As Integer
    Dim FirstTest As Integer
    Dim CommDate As Date
    Dim DOB As Date
    Dim MonthPrem As Long
    Dim SumAssured As Long
    Dim TestCount As Integer

    Set TestFile = ThisWorkbook
    Call Open_Pricing_File
    TestFile.Activate
    PriceFileName = Range("Pricing_File").Value
    Set PriceFile = Workbooks(PriceFileName)
```

Open_Pricing_File opens the file named in "Pricing_File" and when I've stepped through this works. When I try and set PriceFile to this workbook, the code falls over on this last line.

Comment: `PriceFileName = Range("Pricing_File").Value` you should always specify the sheet (and the workbook if you have multiple) the range is on. For best practise use `Testfile.Sheets("your sheet here").Range(` etc. Not sure if that is the issue here, but it is likely. Otherwise it will just take the range of whichever sheet is showing, which might be incorrect.

Comment: The `workbooks` collection refers to the workbooks that are currently open. Is the workbook named after whatever string is stored in `PriceFileName `, open? If you want to open it you need to use the `workbooks.open()` method.

Comment: Plutian: I've updated the code as you suggested and am getting the correct value for PriceFileName in the watch window. Still getting a run time error 9 when I try and name the workbook as PriceFile. The value is "filepath.xlsx" - could the "" around the name be impacting this?

Comment: Stavros Jon: the workbook in PriceFileName is the workbook that gets opened in Open_Pricing_File so will definitely be open. The code is managing to open the file ok and then can't cope.

Comment: Why do you have a separate sub for opening the file? is there a particular reason? If the `Workbooks.Open` line was in this `Get_Sum_Assured` sub, you could `Set` it at that point.

Comment: I agree with CLR, best to `Set` at that point. Another suggestion would be, if through this sub your pricing file is the last to be opened, you could do `Set PriceFile = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)`. It's unreliable if the opening fails or is done manually, but otherwise would solve your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, change your `Open_Pricing_File` sub into a `Function` that returns the opened workbook as an object (Workbook). If you also post the `Open_Pricing_File` we could advise how to do that.

Comment: @Plutian @CLR thanks, I've updated `Open_Pricing_File` and still not had any luck. My code is now: `Set TestFile = ThisWorkbook
    PriceFileName = Range("Pricing_File").Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=PriceFileName
    Set PriceFile = Workbooks(PriceFileName)`. The file opens but can't get past the `Set` line - I haven't really used Set before, am I doing something wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

The following macro opens two workbooks and gives them the name "wb1" and "wb2".
At the end the value from cell A1 is copied from "wb1" to "wb2".

```
Sub copyValue_wb1wb2()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

  'wb1 (workbook1)
  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Data\ExcelFile1.xlsm", Local:=True, ReadOnly:=False
  Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

  'wb2 (workbook2)
  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Data\ExcelFile2.xlsm", Local:=True, ReadOnly:=False
  Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

  'Now you can jump between workbooks like:
  wb1.Activate
  wb2.Activate

  'You can insert a value from wb1 to wb2 like:
  wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. There is no need to use `ActiveWorkbook` at all. Instead: `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Data\ExcelFile1.xlsm", Local:=True, ReadOnly:=False)`